# Should the Router be responsible for network requests? (Backbone.js)

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I'm in disagreement with a co-worker about the responsiblities of a Router. Inside of our single page application, it's my impression to have network requests (AJAX) handled via events being triggered (i.e. Backbone.Events), like so:

```
events : {
    'click a#getUsers' : 'updateModels'
}

updateModels: function() {
    $.ajax(); or this.Model.fetch();
}
```

Yet it is his understanding that network requests should be handled via the router on URL change (depending on a click which changes the url like `a[href="#getThings"]` like so:

```
var App = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "" : "main",
        "thing" : "getThings"
    }

    getThings: function() {
        this.newView = new NewView();
        $.ajax(); // which populates the view with data
    }
});
```

I wanted to know what the backbone reason is for doing network requests.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The vast majority of your AJAX requests should start with a backbone `model` or `collection` and be handled via the `backbone.sync` function. The key methods are `model.fetch()`, `collection.fetch()`, and `model.save()`.

Backbone is flexible and only handles a very primitive set of use cases, so there are cases when you need to step outside these boundaries, but any call to `$.ajax` in a view or a router is a strong code smell of MVC failure.

To address some of your specifics.

> Can a view call `model.fetch()` to load data?

Yes, this is perfectly fine and idiomatic backbone.

> Can a view emit an event which will eventually load data?

Yes, this is perfectly fine. This is only necessary beyond just calling `model.fetch()` as your application grows in complexity and the decoupling that event emitting allows is valuable and warranted. For a todo list, it's usually overkill. For a huge application, this can be a clean approach.

> Does every model fetch cause a change in the browser URL?

No. In fact many single page applications simply live at "/" forever. Routing to unique URLs is optional. Some applications lend themselves easily to it, others not so much. Don't equate "the application needs data X" with "the browser URL needs to be X". These are orthogonal. If a user clicks on the view for "Bill Clinton" in a list of presidents and you want to change the URL to "/presidents/clinton", then go ahead and fire a new route and that makes perfect sense, but sometimes you just want some data without changing the URL.

To summarize the responsibilities of the router, I think of it as follows:

- Based on the URL, which View is supposed to be displayed?
- Also based on the URL, are there model IDs that need to be extracted and instantiated into model instances?
- Wire things up and render the view

So a typical router method pseudocode might be:

- when the URL matches /presidents/:name, respond as follows
- grab the :name parameter and make a President model
- instantiate a PresidentView, passing it the model
- call presidentView.render() and swap the view's element into the DOM at the appropriate spot in the overall page layout

Comment: Thanks for the tremendously helpful answer. I understand that the $.ajax() function call isn't optimum but the json which gets returned in my API is not exactly optimum, as it returns a whole cruft of things which I don't necessarily want polluting my model.

Comment: My methodology is to do the $.ajax() request and both instantiate and set my model inside of the success callback. It is my understanding that the Backbone.fetch() request simply turns the returned json object(s) into an instance of the model, and more often than not, I do not need all of the key/value pairs contained inside of the returned JSON objects returned from the API.

Comment: Override the `parse` method in your models/collections to transform server JSON responses to a backbone-compatible shape.

Answer (score 0):

With Backbone, you should let Backbone be doing most of the ajax requests for you, which will be more often than not triggered from your view, not the router. And I would never use a jQuery ajax request when you could use a Backbone request instead. `this.model.fetch()` is the right way to get the model. I see the router as a way to orient your page, but the finer details should be left to the views. However, choosing between logic in the router vs. in the views/collections/models is more art than science, and I would take a look at other Backbone examples to get more guidance. I think, in a lot of cases, the network requests are handled in the views because it's easier.

In response to your comment below, whenever data is returned from the server, Backbone uses parse to get the information it needs, so rewriting fetch would be a poor decision. You can overwrite the parse method for your model to get the information that you want, and nothing more. i.e.:

```
var YourModel = Backbone.Model.extend({
    parse: function(response) {
        //You can manipulate the object in other ways as well, 
        //but here's how you'd delete info
        delete response.junk;
        return response;
    }
});
```

Similarly, every time you do `this.model.save()`, it uses toJSON() before the model gets sent to the server, which you can also overwrite:

```
toJSON: function() {
    // default -> return _.clone(this.attributes);
    return _new code here_;
}
```

Comment: I understand that this.model.fetch() is optimal for backbone as it sets the models automatically as well. But my API designer is not as finely skilled as others out there (i.e. it returns the object as well as a cruft of other things like a success and fail key value pair). Is there a way to override the .fetch() and .save() requests to take on only what I need?

Comment: @iggy2012 go read up on `parse`: http://documentcloud.github.io/backbone/#Model-parse